# Unable to get partial to display the data the program has calculated`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, coffeescript

Stuck on this problem for days now and already asked one question already with regard to it.

I have an application which displays data for a oil/gas drill in which the user can enter different estimates of what they think the drill may find.  The application correctly calculates results for any change in calculation inputs.  However the results are not displayed on the screen partial for the results.  This is the error I am trying to fix.

Using the google chrome developer tools I can see the results are calculated and the line 
"console.log data" in the file drills.js.coffee produces the JSON response [Object, Object, Object] on the Console and these objects (is that the correct terminology) are present and contain the appropriate data.

I have added in the relevant bits of code from the modules. See below : Controller - App/Assets/Javascript - 2 Views - and in the view files view/projection.js.erb file
(see at bottom)

I have tried/am trying all sorts of methods to try to display the results.  These include

Any help would be great including pointing out something I am trying to do that doesn't make sense.

(1) trying to do so within app/assts/Javascript drills.js.erb. 
This is the line where I try to get the partial to redisplay populated with the correct values from he controller drills action projection

```
$('#id_evaluation_results').html("<%= j render(:partial => '/evaluation_results') %>")
```

doesn't render the partial and results in the text
" <%= escape_javascript render(:partial => '/evaluation_results') %> "
being displayed on the screen.
Changing the double quotes " to single quotes ' causes the error 
SyntaxError: unexpected COMPOUND_ASSIGN
  (in /Volumes/F Drive/drill_investor/app/assets/javascripts/drills.js.coffee)
The addition of the line

(2) I created a file views/drills/projection.js.erb with

```
$('#id_evaluation_results').html('<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => "drills/evaluation_results") %></div>');
```

I don't believe this file is evaluated as making deliberate errors in it does't seem to cause any problem

thanks - Pierre

code below

drills_controller

```
class DrillsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :load_drill, except: [:index, :new, :create]

  def investor
  end

  def projection

    result_list = Evaluation.generate_projection(@drill.drill_interests, assumption_params)
    @result_list= result_list    # this line probably not necessary
  render json: result_list
```

end

App/Assets/Javascript/drills.js.coffee

```
loadAssumptionChange = (drill_id)->
  data = $('#evaluation_assumption_params').serialize()
  console.log data
  $.ajax
    # event.preventDefault()
    url:"/drills/#{drill_id}/projection.json"
    type:"post"
    dataType: 'json'   # data type of response
    data: data
    success: (data,success,xhr)->
      console.log("print data")
      console.log data

     $('#id_evaluation_results').html("<%= j render(:partial => '/evaluation_results') %>")
     # this line not working
```

views/drills/investor.html.erb  -  this is the main screen which includes partial evaluation_results

```
<% content_for :title, "Drill Investor - Valuations" %>
    <div class="form assumption" data-drillid="<%= @drill.id %>">
      <%= render 'assumption_params' %>
    </div>
    <div class="form">
      <div id="id_evaluation_results">
        <%= render 'evaluation_results' %>
      </div>
    </div>       
  </article>
</section>
```

views/drills/evaluation_results.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for :result_list, :html => { class: 'infogroup', id: "evaluation_results",
      :method => :post }, remote: true do |f| %>
  <%= content_tag :header, "Results", class: 'infogroup-header'%>  
  ...
        <th>Discovery Value</th>
        <th>DV/Share</th>
        <th>Leverage</th>
        <th>Risked Lev </th>
        <th>Leverage with CFD's</th>
      </tr>
      <% if @result_list.present? %>
        <% @result_list.each do |result| %>                 
          ....
              <td><%= result.listing_name %></td>
              <td><%= number_to_currency(result.listing.share_price_dollars,
                  :precision => 3, :delimiter => ',')     %></td>
              <td><%= number_to_currency(result.market_capitalisation / 1000000,
                  :precision => 0, :delimiter => ',')     %>M</td>
```

views/drills/projection.js.erb.  This file named to match the action from the controller that should trigger it

```
$('#id_evaluation_results').html('<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => "drills/evaluation_results") %></div>');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two potential problems in your code :

1. `app/assets/javascript/drills.js.coffee` contains erb code (code encapsulated in `<%= %>`) but is not preprocessed by erb : you have to add `.erb` after `.coffee` in filename to add erb preprocessor
2. I think you misunderstand what a preprocessor does : in `drill.js` and `projection.js`, erb will be interpreted only once, when the javascript file is loaded (that is, at the very beginning of the page load)

Once erb have computed data when script is loaded, it will never change : that's preprocessing, not runtime processing.

If you want to load a partial and bind new data to it on the fly, you have to process an other way, like making an ajax request to an action that returns your partial as html and inject it in DOM or use something like mustache to have a template on client side and bind a json response to it.

### loading html directly

Here, instead of responding with json, you respond directly with the html you need. Do not forget to disable layout rendering in your controller, using `render 'your_action', layout: false`.

```
loadAssumptionChange = (drill_id)->
  data = $('#evaluation_assumption_params').serialize()
  $.post( "/drills/#{drill_id}/projection", ( resp ) =>
     $('#id_evaluation_results').html( resp )
  )
```

The avantage of this technique is that it's fairly simple to implement.

The disadvantage is that it's less performant if you load a great quantity of html (client side could process templates more efficiently, while just transfering json data from server side) and that you now have an action dedicated for this client side behavior (action can't be reused for an api, for exemple).

I tend to consider this a bit less "clean" than the alternative.

### loading json bound to mustache

Here, you add your template in page as a mustache script, only load json data from server and render the template on client side.

In your view file, you'll have something like that :

```
<script type="text/mustache" id="results_template">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Discovery Value</th>
        <th>DV/Share</th>
        <th>Leverage</th>
        <th>Risked Lev </th>
        <th>Leverage with CFD's</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      {{#results}}
        <td>{{name}}</td>
        <td>{{price}}</td>
        <td>{{market_capitalisation}}</td>
      {{/results}
    </tbody>
  </table>
</script>
```

You render your json response with everything already preformated (like prices), and use it like that in javascript :

```
loadAssumptionChange = (drill_id)->
  data = $('#evaluation_assumption_params').serialize()

  $.ajax
    url:"/drills/#{drill_id}/projection.json"
    type:"post"
    dataType: 'json'   # data type of response
    data: data
    success: (data,success,xhr)->
      template = $( '#results_template' ).html()
      $('#id_evaluation_results').html( Mustache.render( template, data ) )
```

The advantages are that it's clean, reusable, and can render huge amount of data with no pain (the browser does all the hard work, and it's very good at that).

The disadvantages are that it's more difficult / long to implement and that you can't use any view helper (you have to use them while creating your json response, and pass any value needing helper formatting as json data).

To learn more on client side mustache, [see there](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js).

Comment: Hi, Many hanks for such a complete answer.  I am trying to implment your first answer above.   Thanks - Pierre

Comment: Hi, - trying option 1 above.  Currently getting  500 (Internal Server Error) on the call $.post( "/drills/#{drill_id}/projection", ( resp ) =>.  Investigating now - if you get time or why error occuring could you send response thanks  - Pierre

Comment: A 500 is a server side error, so you're probably good on javascript part. What is the exact error message ? (you can find it in your `rails server` logs just when ajax request is fired)

Comment: Server log = render_output = nil // Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 30660ms // ArgumentError - 'nil' is not an ActiveModel-compatible object that returns a valid partial path.: //       In controller fpr action projection I have only one statement = render 'projection', layout: false

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps problem might be with the double quotes?

```
$('#id_evaluation_results').html(<%= j render(:partial => '/evaluation_results') %>)
```

Comment: Thanks - I just tried the line above and got bug screen "$('#id_evaluation_results').html(<%= j render(:partial => '/evaluation_results') %>)" - SyntaxError: unexpected COMPARE
  (in /Volumes/F Drive/drill_investor/app/assets/javascripts/drills.js.coffee)

Comment: My understanding is that because this line is in the App/assetts/javascripts directory I can't use erb (e.g. render partial).  Puerrr

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you will be able to use erb inside drills.js.coffee because it is not js.erb (and therefore doesn't know how to interpret your <%= #ruby code %>.

That being said, you can definitely render the updated partial with the code that you have in projection.js.erb since it will be called after the controller action. From what I currently see in the code, it is probably not currently called because you need to explicitly tell Rails to respond to javascript like this:

```
 def projection
    @result_list = Evaluation.generate_projection(@drill.drill_interests, assumption_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render :json => @result_list }
      format.js
    end
 end
```

The first format.json tells Rails to render the @result_list as a JSON object (this is used usually via API or in this case I suppose with your first $.ajax call in the drills.js.coffee, the latter format.js is used to tell Rails to render the projection.js.erb template afterwards

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi -thanks for response.  I am trying to implment solution above.  As suggested I have (a) removed attempt to display partial from the app/assets/javscript as this contained erb code (b) I have changed controller projection to above.  However this does not seem to redisplay the partial (_evaluation_results.html.erb).

Comment: Can you test whether your projection.js.erb is getting called?

Comment: To make it work, you probably also have to make sure that your client side form code has the ":remote => true" argument so that rails will make use of rails/jquery-UJS and actually call your partial. A bit more information can be found here http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html

Comment: Took a look again at your form above, seems like remote => true is already there, but can you check where that form is submitting to? It doesn't seem to be submitting to the projection method on your controller.

Comment: Hi (1) dont think drills/projection.js.erb is being called as I put an error in it and error didn't show in the console. (2) The client side partial "_evaluation_results.html.erb" has the remote => true argument but not the main screen "invesotr.html.erb" (3) Where form is submitting to ? - This partial called from "investor.html.erb" which is submitted from investor (as opposed to projection).           THanks Pierre

Comment: Hi - another question from above "Took a look again at your form above, seems like remote => true is already there, but can you check where that form is submitting to?".  The action from Drills controller is investor e.g. (drills/investor)'.  This view associated with this action in the View/Drills/investor wich include the partial invstment_results (initially) blank).  The action "Drills/projection" reponds to changes on the screeen (at leaast that is what I am trying) and updates the investment_results partial.   Does this answer your questions above ? Can I provide further information ? thx